# Combine all printed string get from text file in to one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to **Combine all printed string get from text file in to one list**

My Textfile: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18tYvYs43vA7ib3br1h1VD75OUU5ho1u8

My Full Code:

```
allinstall = open("save_all_install.txt", "r",encoding="UTF-8")

search_words = ["'DisplayName'"]

for line in allinstall:
    if any(word in line for word in search_words):
        # Get the front Display Name Part
        k=line.split('\n')[0]
        #Get the Position I want for excat display name
        print(k[17:-5])
        list = k[17:-5].split(',') 
        # How do I modified here?
        list.extend(list)
        print(list)
```

**Original**

```
Windows Driver Package - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (04/10/2017 14.8.16.1063)
Windows Driver Package - ASUS (ATP) Mouse  (06/17/2015 6.0.0.66)
Windows Driver Package - Intel (MEIx64) System  (10/03/2017 11.7.0.1045)
Windows Driver Package - ASUS (HIDSwitch) System  (08/18/2015 1.0.0.5)
```

**Expected Result**

```
[Windows Driver Package - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (04/10/2017 
14.8.16.1063),Windows Driver Package - ASUS (ATP) Mouse  (06/17/2015 
6.0.0.66),Windows Driver Package - Intel (MEIx64) System  (10/03/2017 
11.7.0.1045),Windows Driver Package - ASUS (HIDSwitch) System  (08/18/2015 
1.0.0.5)]
```

Comment: "Original" and "Result", kind of confusing. Which among these is the expected output?

Comment: The Below one is Expected Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use python keywords, such as `list`, as variable names.

```
allinstall = open("save_all_install.txt", "r",encoding="UTF-8")


search_words = ["'DisplayName'"]
result = []

for line in allinstall:
    if any(word in line for word in search_words):
        # Get the front Display Name Part
        k=line.split('\n')[0]
        #Get the Position I want for excat display name
        print(k[17:-5])
        entry = k[17:-5].split(',') 
        # How do I modified here?
        result.append(entry[0])

print(result)
```

Update:
Here is also a faster and easier maintainable solution to your problem:

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r"'DisplayName', '(.+)'")

with open("save_all_install.txt", "r",encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    allinstall = f.readlines()

result = [re.search(expr, line).group(1) for line in allinstall if re.search(expr, line)]
print(result)
```